# React useLocation causes re-rendering on each page location change

Tags: reactjs

I want everytime the page location changes, it will scroll the screen back to top.

I've tried to use `useLocation()` but it resulted in rendering of whole component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Route with 2 inner routers
const Home = () => {
  console.log("Home Render");
  return (<><Link to="/p1">Page1</Link> | <Link to="/p2">Page2</Link></>);
}

// Routes component
const Pages = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // scroll to top
  }, [useLocation()]);

  return (
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
      <Route path="p1" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="p2" element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
      </Routes>
  )
}

export function App(props) {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Pages />
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Please notice that when clicking on links inside `Home` it renders the whole component, caused by `useLocation()`

Link for the example: https://playcode.io/978267

Comment: What is the issue with entire component getting re-rendered? Unless it is causing any performance issues, it shouldn't matter. To answer why the entire component is getting re-rendered, it is because `useLocation` is internally dependant on `path` from browser router. So, whenever the `path` changes, it will re-render all the components using `useLocation` hook.

Comment: @vighnesh153 Thank you for your response. Re-rendering causes rendering of all component, while i'm rendering specific part on path change. My goal is listener for url change in Pages component.